# Can google assistant ask an specific queestion hourly?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I want to create an app that every hour asks me "What are you doing?" through voice notification.

There are a few ways I can respond, "Working", "Playing", etc.

Then it can log it on my calendar. If this is possible, what are the correct terms that are used to describe this? So I can search for documentation.

Would like to build this with Google Actions https://developers.google.com/actions/  and with Google Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates#push_notifications) feature to trigger the wanted intent where you will prompt the user for the type of activity he/she is doing.

The user can respond and then your webhook can take care of logging to your activity to your calendar using the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview) (Assuming you are referring to Google Calendar)

*Note that this feature is currently in Developer preview and will not work in a production environment. Also it is only intended for Google Assistant on mobile devices. Google Home devices do not support any push notification features at the moment.*

Comment: I'm ok with just having Developer preview. Instead of entering it into Calendar API can I maybe enter somewhere else? I want it to be in the Google home

Comment: If by "I want it to be in the Google home" you mean getting notifications on Google Home it is not possible at the moment